# How to read multiples values from a .txt file?

Tags: python

I got a .txt file that contains multiple lines like this:

```
Hour: 10:51:17, Date: 01/14/2017 -- I: 14.13A V: 178.73V P: 2524.84W
```

How can I read each one of theses values separately?

I've already did a similar procedure in MATLAB using the code below:

```matlab
test_file = fopen('example3.txt');
A = fscanf(test_file,'Hour: %d:%d:%d, Date: %d/%d/%d -- I: %fA V: %fV P: %fW\n',[9,inf]);

data_file =A';
lines = size(A,2);
date1 = data_file(:,7);
date2 = data_file(:,8);
date3 = data_file(:,9)/1000;
```

I would to do a similar procedure in Python, but I can't find a way to read these values. I tried to be more explanatory.

Comment: You will need to further explain what you are trying to do and also provide what you have tried to do so far to solve your task. Usually for these kind of tasks you look to split the line into parameters by some delimiter(s) and then process each parameter (e.g. convert to `datetime`). What are all these parameters and how do you intend to represent them in a graph? Are we talking a chart type [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart) here or a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) data structure (edges, vertices etc.)?

Comment: I'm actually new in Python programming. I've already did this in MATLAB using this code:

test_file = fopen('example3.txt');

A = fscanf(test_file,'Hour: %d:%d:%d, Date: %d/%d/%d -- I: %fA V: %fV P: %fW\n',[9,inf]);
                  
data_file =A';

lines = size(A,2);

date1 = data_file(:,7);
date2 = data_file(:,8);
date3 = data_file(:,9)/1000;

I would to do a similar procedure in Python, but I can't find a way to read these values.
I tried to be more explanatory. Thank you!

Comment: It's fine that you're new to Python, but good Stackoverflow questions include your own attempts at the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking You may [edit] your question to include more information

Comment: You need to parse each line of the file. The [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) regular expression library module would be a good choice.

Comment: Simply tacking your MATLAB code onto the question is not even close to the same as actually trying to write some Python code that does the same thing. No cigar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re

s='Hour: 10:51:17, Date: 01/14/2017 -- I: 14.13A V: 178.73V P: 2524.84W'
m=re.match('Hour: (.+), Date: (.+) -- I: (.+)A V: (.+)V P: (.+)W', s)

list(m.groups())

-> ['10:51:17', '01/14/2017', '14.13', '178.73', '2524.84']
```